# Range/Slice in C++11/1y?

Tags: c++

I could swear C++11 or 1y introduced a feature that allows me to create a range or slice from a vector. Instead of passing around a begin() and end() variable I just use 1 instead. What is the class called?

Comment: I've heard of `array_ref`, but I didn't hear anything of standardization...

Comment: C++11: Nope. C++14 doesn't exist yet, so please consult your crystal ball.

Comment: You could use `v.begin() + offset` and `v.begin() + offset + N` as pair?

Comment: .. or maybe, you're looking for `std::slice`, `std::valarray` and `std::slice_array`?

Comment: Would std::Slice in valarray do the job?

Comment: (Apparently not C++11 or 14 either)

Comment: There's a proposal but it doesn't look active for C++14, must not have been mature enough.  The idea's got some backing from experts with clout, so I'm sure it's not dead, just not here yet.

Comment: @KerrekSB The working draft of C+1y very much does exist and is fully implemented by clang and its standard library, so an entirely valid question.

Comment: I think you are talking about the method `assign` from the `std::vector`; in C++11 it works with ranges too ( but it's not a new thing ).

Comment: @marko: Correcting C++14 (which does not exist) to C++1y (shorthand for the latest draft of what's expected to be voted in as C++14) was reasonable, but Kerrek'c comment was unnecessarily snarky.

Comment: Whats wrong with `template<RandomIt> using range = std::pair<RandomIt,RandomIt>;` ?

Comment: @user2485710: No that doesn't take a range, it takes a pair of iterators.

Comment: @Manu: That won't have `begin()` and `end()` members, or be meaningful to `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, and therefore is unusable with functions that work on standard containers.  (And of course, it's invalid syntax as well)

Comment: @BenVoigt: There have been entirely reasonable things that were at some point part of the working draft but have been voted out since, and with at least two more major meetings coming up, it's really very hard to make predictions about the future, since a lot of things (especially library gadgets like the one in question) can still change.

Comment: @Kerrek: I don't see it on the latest mailing (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/#mailing2014-01) so I think it's out.  Not permanently rejected, but delayed until post-C++14.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm pretty sure that no new features can be introduced to C++14 at this stage.

Comment: @Nawaz: Maybe, I looked [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/operator%5B%5D/) and I can't tell if it makes a copy or doesn't. I DON'T want a copy. I have a `char buf[]` with a FIXED size (4096 atm). I want to use the slice until I'm finished with it in which case i'll modify the buffer. Is slice a good idea to use here? Can I make the slice smaller by writing something like `slice = slice[slice.start+2, slice.end]`

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of [the `Boost::Range` library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) and in particular the `iterator_range` class.

As far as I can tell it's not considered ready for standardization until it gets more real-world use to shake out issues.